# VBA: Trim Cells If Value in Range is

Tags: vba, excel, trim

I have the following challenge:

In a worksheet I need to remove unwanted blanks in a certain range of cells via the trim functionality. This already works fine with the following code:

```
Sub remove_blanks()

Dim rC As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each rC In ActiveSheet.Range("C1:C5000")
    If Not (rC.HasFormula) Then rC = Trim(rC)
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Now I would need to implement a check where the above function should only work if a cell is marked as "YES" in a different column.

E.g.
If in column A a cell value is "YES", only then the above function should work for the same cell in column C.

Kind regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify your line of:

```
If Not (rC.HasFormula) Then rC = Trim(rC)
```

to:

```
If Not (rC.HasFormula) And Range("A" & rC.Row).Value = "YES" Then rC = Trim(rC)
```

This checks that also the value in column "A" in the same row as `rC` equals to "YES"

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using the .Offset

```
If Not rC.HasFormula And rC.Offset(0, [-2]).Value = "YES" Then rC = Trim(rC)
```

Comment: just curious why you need the `[]` for the `-2` ? wouldn't it work just the same with `Offset(0, -2)` ?

Comment: Got an error once (a few years back) and since then I've been using the brackets.